# Proton QPID with standard input

Tags: c++, amqp, qpid

I'm just about to dig into AMQP protocol and things. I'm using [proton](https://qpid.apache.org/proton/index.html) with C++ bindings.

I've stuck with a little problem here.

Say, I have an asynchrnous receiver like in it's example, which one may find in `simple_recv.cpp`. So, the problem I see here is that `proton` has its own mainloop not connected with application's one which may be very usefull if the receiving application is about to process some `stdin` data. 
Hence is my question: is it possible (and how) to process data from `stdin` and still employ asynchronous `proton-qpid` API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I see without creating my own `reactor` or smth like in [here](https://reviews.apache.org/r/32033/diff/1/) is to use multithreaded application and support thread-safety as much as possible.